# yocto: move standard package in another place

Tags: yocto

I have a vendor-provided standard Yocto build I need to customize.

In particular I cannot modify too much the basic filesystem (`/bin` `/sbin` `/usr/bin` `/usr/sbin` ...) because it gets installed in a quite full NAND Flash.

If I want to add something "non trivial" I need to move it somewhere else (e.g.: `/usr/local` or `/opt`) in a brand new filesystem (e.g.: on SD storage) and later mount it in the "right place".

How can I "relocate" a standard package to be built in some other place?

Example: If I want to add "native" compilation to my system I need to add something like `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " packagegroup-core-buildessential"` somewhere (e.g.: in `.../poky/build/conf/local.conf`).

This will fail because of full partition (unsurprisingly). I can force production of packages (`.ipk`, in my case) but those will try to install in the same place (and fail because filesystem is a readonly `squashfs` and it would be too small even if writable) hence the question:

How do I tell a standard `packagegroup` should be put in another location (e.g.: `usr/local`)?

Specific pointers to documentation would be welcome; I tried searching the Mega-Manual, but I didn't find the right spell to use.